# Pinescript v5 - How to declare float series

Tags: pine-script, series, pine-script-v5

I have declare:

```
type valutaType
    string valuta
    float level

var arrayValute = array.new<valutaType>()
```

Wrote down this method:

```
getLevelFromCurrency(currency) =>
    var levels = array.new_float()
    for item in arrayValute
        if item.valuta == currency
        levels := item.level
```

I receive this errors:

> Variable 'levels' was declared with 'float[]' type. Cannot assign it expression of type 'series float'

How to declare levels in getLevelFromCurrency(currency) as float series instead array of float?

I've tried:

- array.new_float()
- series

Added a tiny test-script:

```
//@version=5
indicator("testScriptV5", precision=2, overlay=true)

type valutaType
    string valuta
    float[] level

var arrayValute = array.new<valutaType>()

sma200 = ta.sma(close, 200)

array.push(arrayValute, valutaType.new("EUR", sma200))
levelssss = array.new_float()

for item in arrayValute
    if item.valuta == "EUR"
        levelssss := item.level

plot(levelssss)
```

Answer (score 1):

You declare `levels` as an array here : `var levels = array.new_float()`.

Then you try to assign `item.level` to it which is not correct. `item.level` is of type `float`.

`levels := item.level`.

If you want to store `item.level` whenever your conditions is `true`, you can just push it to your array.

```
getLevelFromCurrency(currency) =>
    var levels = array.new_float()
    for item in arrayValute
        if item.valuta == currency
            array.push(levels, item.level)
```

Comment: That's correct, but didn't resolve my problem. 
I add a tiny script in the first post to explain the problem better.